# Linux Mint- Have to constantly reset my internet to work?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, linux-mint

I bought [this ASUS desktop](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00SXRQ3IK) recently and dual-booted it with Windows and Linux Mint. It comes with an antenna for WiFi.

However, on Linux Mint my home network connection keeps dropping and it disconnects at random moments (every 5-10 minutes). I have to run these commands whenever it happens to restart the wlan. I even put it in a shell script, but it is annoying I have to do this. How do I fix this specific driver?

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

Comment: What's the output of `lspci | grep -i network` and `lsusb | grep -i network`?

Comment: It reads `04:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter`
and 
`Bus 003 Device 005: ID 13d3:3414 IMC Networks`

Comment: Have you tried this one already? http://forum.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=53&p=1008186#p1007308. Try to reboot after that command.

Comment: Man I hate networking... let me see if I can try making the IP not static.

Comment: I'll let you know what happens and if it stays connected. Feel free to post your suggestion as an answer and I'll mark it if its successful.

Comment: Dang it, the connection still is going out.

Comment: The driver for your WiFi controller is still very buggy. You'd have to compile a newer version of the driver (called rtlwifi) or get a cheap USB WiFi adapter that has been in the market for some time (more than one year) and disable the on-board WiFi controller.

Comment: I was wondering about that. I'll see if I can compile that driver and if not, I'll just buy a dongle.

Answer (score 0):

### For people still googling this in the future (like me)

I had the same problem with a Realtek RTL8191SEvB Wireless LAN Controller (from the tty output of lspci)

I created a script to run every 5mins which checks if it's working and if not - resets it automatically.

Here's the script (requires wget and NetworkManager):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Use wget to get the status of connection
wget -q --spider http://google.com > /dev/null

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
   STATUS="Online"
else
   STATUS="Offline" 
fi

# Use NetworkManager (via nmcli) to reboot the wifi if necessary
 
if [ $STATUS =  "Online" ]; then
    echo "$(date +%r\ %a\ %d\ %b) : WiFi check OK" >> /full/path/to/your/textlog
    echo >> /full/path/to/your/textlog
    exit    
else
    echo "$(date +%r\ %a\ %d\ %b) : WiFi check BAD" >> /full/path/to/your/textlog
    nmcli radio wifi off > /dev/null 
    nmcli radio wifi on > /dev/null
    echo "$(date +%r\ %a\ %d\ %b) : Restarting..." >> /full/path/to/your/textlog
    sleep 3
    nmcli dev wifi connect "Galaxy A12E23D" > /dev/null
    echo "$(date +%r\ %a\ %d\ %b) : Back online!" >> /full/path/to/your/textlog
    echo >> /full/path/to/your/textlog
fi
```

Save in your favorite scripts folder and then to have it run every 5mins, you edit the crontab file as root (cron is the linux scheduling program). In the terminal login as root:

```
sudo -i
```

Then:

```
crontab -e
```

And add the following line to the file that opens:

```
*/5 * * * * /path/to/your/script.sh
```

Save and exit and you're done.

```
logout
```

I'm sure there's some way to treat the cause instead of the symptom, but you don't even notice this going on in the background. It's just an easy workaround.

If you found this on google because your RTL8191SE doesn't work at all, it could very well be that you're using a non-proprietary kernel which doesn't have drivers for your card. Have a noodle around and you should be able to find a release of your distro that includes proprietary drivers in the kernel. Then come back here to fix the above problem.

I hope this helps somebody.